# AsyncPostBackTrigger not firing on load of user control

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have an update panel which refreshes a user control. The update panel is set to conditional, and the condition is on a textbox control. Using AsyncPostBackTrigger, to fire when the text changes in the textbox, it works fine. However, what I am not getting is when the page is first loaded, and the textbox is populated with data is that it is not firing the postback trigger.

Is there a way of forcing it fire when the page is loaded for the first time?

I have tried simple things such as UpdatePanel.Update(), or txtbox.text = string.empty to force it to recognise a change- but no luck.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code. That's important. It seems like you're confusing when things are happening in the page lifecycle.

Comment: why do you want it to fire when the page is first loaded?

Comment: There are two parts to this-one for the update panel to refresh or I should say the usercontrol to refresh when the user changes a value in the textbox; two when the user first goes to the page, and the page loads with initial date - set by the application to fire off the event. So it is initial first load, plus user interaction with the page

Comment: Try to set a client script to set a value into the textbox when the page is loaded, use Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

Comment: I don't think this would work, because the value set in the textbox has come via web service based upon alot of other factors.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace with your ids

```
 private void tb_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextStateChanged((TextBox)sender);

    }

    UpdateSite.txtPhone.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(tb_Loaded);
```